# Следить за местом на linux сервере

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Подскажите как можно следить за свободным местом на сервере ubuntu и как то предупреждало чтобы администратора о больших файлах, о то что мало осталось места?

Comment: `$ df -l --output=pcent | grep -q '\(99\|100\)%' && echo "мало места однако!"`

Comment: Следить вручную можно `df -h`, `du -sh some/file`, комбинируя с `watch`. Для большей автоматизации, возможно, лучше пойдёт Python

Comment: вопрос чрезмерно широк: 1. «как-то предупреждало» — нужна конкретика. 2. «о больших файлах» и «о том, что мало осталось места» — это вообще два разных вопроса, причём оба требуют конкретизации.

Comment: Взять любую из существующих систем мониторинга да и всё

Comment: думаю не следить, а мониторить удаленно тогда - Google: zabbix, netdata, munin, nagios

Comment: ulimit’ы настроить и забыть.

Comment: А какие есть существующие стстемы?

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг смотрите мой коментарий. Я развертываю полный мониторинг на  Zabbix/Netdata/Phromethus/Grafana  с оповещением по электронной почте, Телеграм и Слак.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конкретную задачу можно решить с помощью `cron` и скрипта на вашем любимом языке, который будет смотреть на вывод `df` (для определения остатка места) и `find / -size +100500M` для поиска больших файлов.

А для более широкой задачи «следить за сервером» я бы рекомендовал Zabbix или Nagios — они специально для этого придуманы.